# Usar substr diretamente num foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

```
foreach ($exibe as $u) {
                echo "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='thumbnail'> ";
                echo "<img src='{$u->imagem}' height='120px' class='img-thumbnail'>";
                echo "<div class='caption'><h6>{$u->titulo}</h6>";
                echo "</div></div></div>";
```

Estou tentando  exibir apenas os caracteres inicial:

```
echo substr ({$u->titulo},0,50);
```

Porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Testa `echo "<div class='caption'><h6>".substr($u->titulo, 0, 50)."</h6>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A minha solução seria fazer uso da função [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) para recolher X caracteres, passando o resultado para a função [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para quebrar a saída em linhas e finalmente ficar apenas com a primeira linha que é efetivamente o pretendido:

```
$titulo = explode("\n", wordwrap($u->titulo, 50))[0];
```

## Exemplo:

```
$titulo = "Isto é um título de alguma coisa que carece ter um título, mas como é muito grande, vou cortar e meter uns pontinhos no final";

$manter = 50;

$titulo = explode("\n", wordwrap($titulo, $manter))[0];

var_dump($titulo);  // Saída: string(49) "Isto é um título de alguma coisa que carece ter"
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/X8V7Ir).

Desta forma, estamos a partir a string mas a evitar partir palavras ao meio.

## Para o teu caso:

Para o teu caso em particular ficaria:

```
foreach ($exibe as $u) {

  $titulo = explode("\n", wordwrap($u->titulo, 50))[0].'...';

  echo '
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="'.$u->imagem.'" height="120px" class="img-thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <h6>'.$titulo.'</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>';
}
```

Exemplo do resultado final no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56qjd6bx/).

[image: Captura de tela de simulação do resultado]

---

## Considerações

Ao cortarmos uma *string* para posteriormente adicionar `...`, temos que estar atentos a duas coisas:

1. Não partir as palavras ao meio para não perder leitura:

   Já vimos em cima como lidar com isto.
2. Não adicionar `...` se efetivamente não existiu um corte:

   Para este caso, podemos otimizar o código passando o trabalho do corte para uma função, função essa que ao devolver o resultado verificará primeiro se efetivamente existiu um corte na *string* fornecida:

   ```
   /**
    * Cortar String
    * Vai cortar a string recebida e adicionar "..." apenas se a mesma
    * tiver mais caracteres do que os indicados para manter.
    *
    * @param string $str String a cortar
    * @param integer $keep Número de caracteres a manter (por defeito 50)
    *
    * @return string Texto pronto a usar
    */
   function cortarStr ($str, $keep=50) {

     if (strlen($str)>$keep)
       $str = explode("\n", wordwrap($str, 50))[0] . '...';

     return $str;
   }
   ```

   Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/BwAZCw).

Answer (score 5):

Algum problema em fazer isto?

```
foreach ($exibe as $u) {
    $titulo = substr($u->titulo, 0, 50);
    echo "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='thumbnail'> ";
    echo "<img src='{$u->imagem}' height='120px' class='img-thumbnail'>";
    echo "<div class='caption'><h6>{$titulo}</h6>";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
}
```

Outra forma:

```
foreach ($exibe as $u) {
    echo "<div class='col-md-3'><div class='thumbnail'> ";
    echo "<img src='{$u->imagem}' height='120px' class='img-thumbnail'>";
    echo "<div class='caption'><h6>".substr($u->titulo, 0, 50)."</h6>";
    echo "</div></div></div>";
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/SubstrInTemplate.php).

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda bigown  mais acabei optando por usar jquery:    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  $(".limit").each(function(i){
    len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>90)
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,100)+'...');
    }
  });       
});
</script>